# Is 'shovey' or 'shovy' a legitimate word meaning 'pushy'?

Tags: meaning, parts-of-speech, is-it-a-word

I heard an American say the word 'shovey' or 'shovy' along with another word 'pushy'. In context, the latter was used to mean "unpleasantly self-assertive" or something. So, I could easily understand that the former was used in a similar sense.

But no dictionary I've consulted lists 'shovey' or 'shovy' as a word, not even in some slang dictionaries.

So I was wondering if 'shovey' or 'shovy' is a legitimate English word, and if so which one is the correct spelling.

Comment: I do not believe shovy is in any way a correct spelling at all. Where have you seen this spelling used?

Comment: It seems apropos that you heard *shovy* (the arbitrary spelling I adopt) "along with" *pushy* since the examples cited in the answer and in the comments invite the conclusion that this is the only context you'll find *shovy* in. Similar to *dovey* which probably doesn't occur much outside of *lovey dovey*, although the two phenomena may not be  exactly the same.

Comment: It is a legitimate English word because it is based on an existing word and uses the standard rules of word formation (adding the bound morpheme **-y** to indicate something with the given nature; e.g. reddy, smiley, etc). The fact that is has not been used widely enough to appear in dictionaries doesn't mean it isn't a word.

Answer (score 3):

I've never heard it used, and the *OED* is unaware of its existence, however it does appear in print.  From the 2001 book *[Women College Basketball Coaches](https://books.google.com/books?id=jZOFQ0cfxw4C&pg=PA82&dq=%22shovey%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjvgvKio57JAhWDFz4KHdPCBu04ChDoAQgbMAA#v=onepage&q=%22shovey%22&f=false)* by Rosemarie Skaine.

> When we were in college, we could be assertive, pushy and **shovey**
>   on the basketball court, but we had to go into the locker room to
>   change into frilly blouses and skirts.

Comment: Situations are often described as "pushy and shovey" in my neck of the woods. So it's definitely a word, even if the dictionaries haven't caught up with it yet.

Comment: @ralph.m What godforsaken neck of the woods do you live in?

Comment: A very pushy and shovey neck of the woods—down here in kangaroo land. :-)

Comment: I'm not sure that the fact that a Physical Education teacher got a book published should move the needle on acceptable English usage.

Answer (score -2):

When push came to shove, the speaker should have used 'pushy', (as 'shovey' is not a real word, no matter which way you spell it).